# Регулярное выражение: как прописать выражение чтобы оно брало определенное соответствие?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Имеется текст, заключенный в `< >`, я его отбираю регулярным выражением `<.*?>`, но как мне дописать это регулярное выражение, чтобы оно всегда брало 4-е совпадение (в данном случае `<фрукты>`), а остальные не трогало? Это нужно для замены текста, чтобы не все теги заменять а только определенные.

```
<игра>
<автобус>
<деньги>
<фрукты>
<сельдерей>
```

Comment: Во-первых, вам надо понять критерий жадности, во-вторых, задача станет намного понятнее, и вы сами сможете её решить.

Comment: А значит "4 совпадение"?

Comment: /(?:\s?<.*?>\s?){3}(<.*?>)/isu

Comment: @Алексей Обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Просто записываете в регулярку те тэги, которые надо.

```
<(?:игра|автобус|деньги|фрукты|сельдерей)>
```

### UPDATE

Да просто возьмите регулярку `<.*?>` и возьмите четвёртое соответствие. Это проще всего.

Comment: Вы забыли `<` и `>` определить, как символы `\<...\>`

Comment: @Yuri [Неправда](https://regex101.com/r/Ntl80H/1)

Comment: Пардон, и так работает. Но я обычно определяю, как символы :)

Comment: Извините что всех запутал, но мне нужно с помощью регулярного выражения заменить на странице определенный (по порядку) </div>

Comment: Просто взять регулярку <.*?> и взять 4 совпадение не могу, закрытый скрипт замены текста непозволяет

Comment: @Алексей во-первых помните об [этом](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1548895), во-вторых ваши новые замечания прекрасно подходят для нового вопроса. Потому что это кардинально меняет вопрос и ответ на него.

Answer (score 1):

Регулярка

```
/(?:\s?<.*?>\s?){3}(<.*?>)/isu
```

Рабочий пример https://regex101.com/r/J3oGUo/1

Comment: если в обычной html странице регулярным выражением искать 4 или 7 </div> ?